# QGIS-Python Icon in label

Tags: python, qgis, plugins

I am working with python plugins for qgis.I developed my plugin and incooperated into QGIS locally. 
My plugin name is **DlgAbout.py**.It has label named **logo** ,used to place image in it.The code is

```
self.logo.setPixmap( QtGui.QPixmap( "icons/bannertile.PNG" ) )
```

When i run the same normally,it is shown properly
[image]

But when i incooperate the same into QGIS,the logo is not shown.

[image]

My file **DlgAbout.py** path is **C:\rt_sql_layer_ui** and icons are in **C:\rt_sql_layer_ui\icons**.
What can be the problem??

I tried something like this:

```
self.logo.setPixmap( QtGui.QPixmap( ":/icons/bannertile.PNG" ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is create a [Qt resource file](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html) and then you can use the `":/icons/bannertile.PNG"` syntax.

Use pyrcc4 to complie the .qrc file.